# Android alert dialog using custom view issue on Lollipop

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I am displaying an alert dialog with four buttons in my app, and it displays quite nicely on Android devices pre Lollipop. However, on a Lollipop device, the buttons are all white, as in the attached screenshot.

Can someone tell me if I must add something to make this compatible with Android Lollipop?

EDIT

This issue actually applies to all buttons in the app, so perhaps it has something to do with Button styles. Another clue is that I am using the v7 App compatibility jar with this app, since the app was to support old Android 2.1.

As a result of this, I will include the part of the manifest that may be an important clue to solve this.

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" ...>


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Here is the layout xml, as requested.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout android:padding="7dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Result" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/textResult"/>


    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/row1" android:layout_below="@+id/textResult">


      <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" android:text="@string/reviewhand" android:id="@+id/reviewhand" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" android:text="@string/reviewbids" android:id="@+id/reviewbids" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"/>

      </TableRow>


      <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" android:text="@string/reviewkitty" android:id="@+id/reviewkitty" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" android:text="@string/menu_scoreboard" android:id="@+id/scoreboard" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Problem alert dialog]

... and how it is before Lollipop
[image]

Comment: Seems like it could be the `Button` `style`? Maybe post your `XML` for the dialog/buttons for better help.

Comment: Yes layout code please.

Comment: I have just found out that all buttons are affected, not just the button in a custom view of an alert dialog. Help!

Comment: How does it appear for pre-lollipop devices ? What do you want the background color to be ?

Comment: Added the screenshot using Android 4 device...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this, by installing the latest Android Support Library (v 22.2.1), and re-compiling the app. Thanks for your previous suggestions anyway.